# SQL: Selecting distinct values for another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to determine how many unique values from one column can be grouped by values in another column.

There are many columns in my sheet, but the ones I'm interested in are: 'department' and 'user'

How the data is that for these two columns, there are repeat users with the same department.

Eg.

```
Department    User

Insights      Mike

Insights      Mike

Insights      Chris

Market        Julie

Research      Will

Research      Sabrina

Research      Bryan
```

What I would want is the following:

```
Department    DistinctUsers

Insights       2

Market         1

Research       3
```

My basic SQL knowledge tells me this is the structure of the code:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(DISTINCT user) 
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY department, user
```

I have seen that people would implement **`(SELECT DISTINCT User from Sheet1)`** in the **`FROM`** clause, but I have failed to integrate that into the code.

Any suggestions or tips is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: From your explanation, your query should work. But sample data and expected output is needed. Your attempt at sample data is unclear.

Comment: My error seems to come with the 'COUNT(Distinct user)'.  Essentially I'm looking to group the departments and count the unique users in each department - hope that clears it up a bit

Comment: Well, that's exactly what that query does. Just remove the `user` from the `group by`. Also mysql <> sql server. Pick one tag. Also what does this have to do with ms-access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to remove users from the group by.

```
SELECT 
   department, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT [user]) as CT
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY department
```

**ACCESS**

```
SELECT
   department,
   count([user])
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT department, [user] from Sheet1) as x
GROUP BY
   department
```

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to have it work in Microsoft Access as well?

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server (and some other databases).  You might have to escape it to get your query to run.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will do the job, but no need to group by the user

Comment: This is incorrect and will display 3 users for the department `Insights`, instead of the expected 2

Comment: I've amended my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #TMP (Department  NVARCHAR(50),Name NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TMP
SELECT 'Insights', 'Mike' UNION ALL

SELECT 'Insights','Mike' UNION ALL

SELECT 'Insights','Chris'UNION ALL

SELECT 'Market'   ,'Julie' UNION ALL

SELECT 'Research',  'Will'UNION ALL

SELECT  'Research', 'Sabrina'UNION ALL

SELECT  'Research','Bryan'

SELECT * FROM #TMP

SELECT department, COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) 
FROM #TMP
GROUP BY department

ROLLBACK TRAN
```